# List of all style parameters used in the wx.Frame style bitmask

Tags: coding-style, wxpython

Getting a listing of all wxPython events is possible using:

```
import wx
for x in dir(wx):
    if x.startswith('EVT_'):
     print x
```

How do I get the list of all style parameters used in defining the wx.Frame style bitmask?